# translation of "Der kanonische Modul ..."

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Do you know a note that is the translation of the following in English?

> J. HERZOG et al., "Der kanonische Modul eines Cohen-Macaulay-Rings," Lecture Notes in Mathematics No. 238, Springer-Verlag, Berlin/Heidelberg/New York, 1971.

It seems that Bruns-Herzog have some parts of it. But I want complete translation.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean a traslation of the whole paper? There are papers and even Eisenbud's book that mention it with its original german name and date 1971 as the original one. It may well be there is no translation to english...but if there is no translation of Huppert's excellent book in finite groups then no surprise here. German is a good language to learn, at least for translation of mathematical papers.

Comment: It is more or less a book from seminars I believe. But I am curious why one wants the whole translation?

Comment: in papers authors refer to it.